When does $-(-v)=v$ not hold?
I am going through some simple questions in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right and for each I'm trying to come up with "motivation" for why these things must be proved.
Examples:

We want to prove distributivity of multiplication over addition holds in the complex numbers but in some cases it doesn't like: there exists functions $f,g,h$ such that $f\circ(g+h)\neq f\circ g+f\circ h$ but funnily enough $(f+g)\circ h=f\circ h+g\circ h$.


We want to prove that if $a\in\mathbb F$ and $v\in V$ where $V$ is a vector space, if $av=0$ this implies $a=0$ or $v=0$ because stuff like Showing AB=0 does not imply either A,B=0, but that singular can happen (two things multiplied together can be 0 but neither of those things are 0)

but I cannot think of any structures or things where multiplying by -1 twice does not result in the same thing. Perhaps there's some other motivation why this is the case? Or is this purely for general mathematical rigorous practice?
Looking mainly for motivation that can be understood by students taking their first course in linear algebra but more advanced motivation, for myself, is also very welcome.

Would you count structures where you can't in general multiply by $-1$, i.e. additive inverses don't always exist? (To take a simple example, string concatenation.)

It's really hard to understand what you're asking. The quotes aren't talking about -(-v) at all. Every theorem, no matter how simple, has to be proved.

@J.G. Interesting thought. I would generally like to find a structure that could feasibly be multiplied by -1 twice and somehow yield something different but the more I think about it the more I think there is no proper example of that. What you said is definitely a good runner-up for that. Thank you.

Bear in mind if $-v$ is defined by $(-v)+v=0$ then $-(-v)$ is defined by $-(-v)+(-v)=0=(-v)+v$, so if $+$ is commutative & cancellative $-(-v)=v$.

@TomekCzajka I clearly marked that the quotes are examples of concrete motivation for proving certain properties and that I'm looking for the same for this question. And I did ask at the end whether this might just be for general rigorous mathematical practice, so I understand the importance of proving everything. I am simply looking for good examples that will motivate Linear Algebra students to understand things that may look pointless to prove, but it's still important to do so as there may be wacky cases where it actually doesn't hold.

@J.G. very very good point, perhaps enough of a corollary of the existence of additive inverse to spark motivation in both areas! Thank you for brainstorming this.

Here is an example of an "-" operation for which it doesn't hold. Define A = {Monday, Tuesday, ..., Sunday}, and define an operation "-x" on this set as mapping each day to the previous day. -Monday = Sunday, -Tuesday = Monday, etc. Now -(-Monday) = Saturday, so -(-x) = x doesn't hold.

@TomekCzajka Ooh this is actually quite lovely. I wish I was exposed to more examples like this early on in my math career. Might be a bit scary for them to see "-" redefined like this but it is such a simple example that this would be the perfect introduction to seeing something like this!

I've proposed a string class where s -= t removes one occurence of the substring $t$, while s %= t removes all occurrences.  Nobody else liked the idea, though.

@TomekCzajka Writing $x-1$ as $-x$, even if it is modulo $7$, obviously contradicts $-(-x)=x$, but I don't think the question was about whether arbitrary unary operators satisfy that identity.

@Dan might be a bit harder to picture to students just getting into any sort of theoretical/proof-based math. I don't exactly have a good basis for this but I'm sure anyone interested in (computer science and is getting into the more mathy elements) or number theory would love that example. Maybe I just think that way because of the notation used.

@J.G. I definitely see your point though I do like the idea of still using this as a slight introduction to how we can do these sorts of manipulations/redefining of familiar operation on a set we are all familiar with. Also then the fact that -(-(-(-(-(-(-x))))))=x works for $x\in A = {$Monday, Tuesday, $\dots$, Sunday$}$ while it doesn't for any $x\in\mathbb R\setminus{0}$ is very fun.

@J.G. I interpreted the question as asking about arbitrary unary operators, and how the - operator in linear spaces differs in that respect from some other operator in some other spaces. The author seems to concur. I don't know how else to interpret the question.

"Define A = {Monday, Tuesday, ..., Sunday}, and define an operation "-x" on this set as mapping each day to the previous day. "  In what sense does the "day before" represent the "negative" of the day?  If "$-$" doesn't mean the additive inverse, there is no reason to call it "$-$" and could just as easily call it $figtree$.  That $figtree(figtree\ a)\ne a$ is no more interesting than noting $(a^2)^2 \ne a$ or $5(5a^2 + 7) + 7 \ne a$.

Aside

I cannot think of any structures or things where multiplying by -1 twice does not result in the same thing.

I want to emphasize that that is technically a different question than in the title about $-(-v)=v$. $-(-v)=v$ is literally saying something about "the negation of the negation", and isn't necessarily in a context where multiplication makes sense.
However, if someone is writing $-v$ then they're probably working in an abelian group (at least an abelian subgroup of a semigroup). And in that case, we can view the abelian group as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, so that the (scalar) multiplication in the module by $-1$ does indeed correspond to negation.
In other words, a context that allows you to write $-v$ is almost certainly a context that arguably allows you to call that "multiplying by $-1$", even if it's unusual to speak of multiplication in that context.
Examples
Examples for Students

Looking mainly for motivation that can be understood by students taking their first course in linear algebra

The standard sorts of examples are simply to define it in some wrong way that doesn't yield an involution. Here are some assorted examples that could be used in a Linear Algebra class:

For $\mathbb R^3$ with the usual scalar multiplication, define $-\mathbf v$ to be
$7\mathbf v$.
For $\mathbb R^2$ with the usual addition, define $-\langle a,b\rangle$ to be $\langle -a,-b-1\rangle$.
For the positive reals with "vector addition" temporarily defined to be usual multiplication, define $-x$ to be $e^x$ (instead of the correct $x^{-1}$ or usual negation which would go outside the set).
For $\mathbb R$, define $-x$ to be $\sin x$.
For $\mathbb R$, define $-x$ to be the usual negative except that $-4=13$ instead.

Examples for Mathematicians?
If there were a situation where multiplying by $-1$ twice didn't result in the same thing, then that multiplication wouldn't be associative even for things corresponding to integers, which would be highly unusual.
And if there were a situation where the negation of the negation didn't result in the original, then we'd have $-(-x)=-(-x)+0=-(-x)+\left((-x)+x\right)\ne \left(-(-x)+(-x)\right)+x=0+x=x$, so that addition couldn't be associative, which would perhaps even more unusual.
There are some examples* where something that is an involution (or negation) in one context stops being an involution in a broader context. However, to my knowledge, mathematicians have consistently chosen not to use a minus sign if it's not an involution.
* For example, taking the dual space in linear algebra is basically an involution in the finite-dimensional case, but not in the infinite-dimensional case. And "swapping the roles of the two players" is the negation of a game in the standard "normal play" context in Combinatorial Game Theory, but is no longer the negation under the "misère play condition" (and so the standard notation changes to accommodate that).

Opinion
I think the premise of the question is a little backwards to how most mathematicians would think about this sort of thing.
The reason we prove that multiplication in some context is commutative is not "because sometimes (e.g. in the context of matrix multiplication) multiplication is not commutative". Rather, mathematicians just happened to make the decision to call things like matrix multiplication "multiplication" even though they're not commutative.
In another language or a parallel universe, we could certainly agree to call/notate things as "multiplication" only when the operation is commutative. And then we could use another notation and another word ("distributation"?) for operations that distribute over addition but are not commutative. (In fact, this is essentially what is done in the Wolfram Language featured in Mathematica: There, * is multiplication when commutative, . is matrix multiplication, and ** can be used to denote some other non-commutative multiplication.)
It so happens that to deny $-(-x)=x$ would be a step too far for people, and so things that don't satisfy that identity aren't allowed in our culture to use the symbol "$-$" or words like "negation". That's just to avoid confusion, and not based on some fundamental mathematical truth.
Motivation

Or is this purely for general mathematical rigorous practice?
I'd say "yes and no".

Sometimes we prove something that seems pretty intuitive/obvious just to be rigorous. But it can also be helpful for explaining something or convincing others of something.
For an example at the student level, suppose that you have a new idea for a vector space, like "functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ under addition and scalar multiplication by $\mathbb R$". Maybe it's completely intuitive to you that this is a vector space and should satisfy all the axioms of vector spaces. But if I'm a fellow student, and the only vector spaces I've seen are finite dimensional, I could be quite skeptical that it's a vector space. If you prove all the properties, then I can't deny it.
Similarly, at the research level, if you want to present a new thingy, and it's very intuitive to you since you've been researching it for weeks, then you'd better show me at least a sketch of the proof that it really is a thingy since I don't have that familiarity with it yet.
